# Convert Unicode \u009e to acute accent from JSON

Tags: objective-c, unicode, diacritics, data-conversion, nsjsonserialization

I am using Xcode in objective-C and I try to figure out how I could convert "\U009e" character to "é" but I am still stuck despite a lot of discussions about this topic.

Basically, I have created inside my Xcode project a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
"ééé":["1"],
}
```

When I get the file by the NSJSONSerialization method:

```
NSString *dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"json"];
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath] options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

I end up with unicode characters (like \U009e) instead of an acute accent. I know I need to find a way to convert/decode/... during the process but I don't know how to do it.

Would anyone have an idea?

Comment: Don't be confused that `NSLog` displays the Unicode representation of non-ASCII characters. Assign the value to a label or text field and the value is displayed correctly.

Comment: In fact I get the same error when displaying it in an alertController where I would like to have it without those special characters.

Comment: Is the file saved UTF-8 encoded? Usually the framework treats unicode characters correctly.

Comment: Yes it is saved in UTF-8. In fact it is displayed correctly in a tableview but not in my alertController

Comment: The wrong format was displayed only when showing strings inside array/dictionary. Everything was fixed when creating an NSString from the content. Sorry for the inconvenience.